# How to use array of objects as lookup table based on property name

Tags: javascript, arrays, lookup-tables

From https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/25858/json-lookup-by-key
I have the following which works:

```
var data = [
        {
            "Key": "2222-2222-2222",
            "Email": "a@test.com"
        },
        {
            "Key": "1111-1111-1111",
            "Email": "test@test.com"
        }
    ],
    lookup = {};

// generate the lookup table for reuse
data.forEach(function (el, i, arr) {
    lookup[el.Key] = el.Email;
});

// returns 'test@test.com'
print(lookup['1111-1111-1111']);
```

What I want to do is(pushing works, accessing does not):

pushing(test data population):

```
var list = [];
for(someCount){
   var uniqueID = uuidv4();
   var objToAdd = {};
   var objChild = {};
   objChild.var1 = 1;
   objChild.var2 = 2;

   objToAdd[uniqueID] = objChild;
   list.push(objToAdd);
}
```

read/access:

```
var var1Val = list[uniqueID].var1

or

for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    if(list[i] === uniqueID){
        var var1Val = list[i].var1
    }
}

Also whats the proper way to check:
if(list[uniqueID] === undefined)
```

I'm trying to compare the performance of using a property name as an key for a look up table, opposed to a loop, as the array could have 1000's of elements and be accessed 1000's of times per second.

**Edit:**
After a bit more research powered by the answers of Adrian Brand and CertainPerformance, It became clear I was trying to create a associative array using a actual Array, which javascript does not support. It seems though you can add named arrray elements but you can not access them by name, only by integer. (beware, I believe I read this leads to unexpected states)

As shown below the only option is to use a plain object. Surprisingly is very performant.

Also interesting post on 'undefined': [Detecting an undefined object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property)

Wish I could select both Adrian Brand and CertainPerformance answers as they both helped immensely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you're pushing an object with a single `uniqueID` property to the array; `list[someUniqueId]` won't work, because a `uniqueID` would be a property of an *item in the array*, not the array itself. Just use an object instead:

```
var listObj = {};
for(someCount){
  var uniqueID = uuidv4();
  listObj[uniqueID] = {
    var1: 1,
    var2: 2,
  };
}
```

And then you can access with

```
var var1Val = list[uniqueID].var1
```

If you have indicies that you're always accessing the properties from (that is, `uniqueID`s), probably best not to use an array anywhere in the code.

> Also whats the proper way to check:
>
> ```
> if(list[uniqueID] === undefind)
> ```

Just change to `undefined`, and that should work just fine.

Comment: Updated OP, undefind was a typo. Thank you the tailored example, helped A LOT as I'm learning JS. Would give a upvote if my rep was high enough.

Comment: The answer you accepted is incorrect. Compare the time required for `.find` https://jsfiddle.net/unszemLp/ vs the time required for property lookup https://jsfiddle.net/gpfyo7Ld/ , property lookup is *much, much faster*.